# Jquery validation Plugin required field dependency

Tags: jquery

Using Jquery validation plugin, i am trying to validate a field companyid2 and display an error message if the user did not enter companyid1. If user enters companyid 2, companyid1 field should not be empty in this case.The problem is i dont see the error message "Enter company 1" if the user enters any value less than 13 in companyid1 field. i tried to put an alert to check what actually is being returned by $("#company1").val() < 13. it does return true but for some reason the message is not getting displayed.or it does not trigger the error.

below is my code,

```
<label  for="company1">Company 1:</label> 
<input id="company1" name="company1" type="text" value=""/> 
<label  for="company2" > To:</label>
<input id="company2" name="company2" type="text" value=""/> 



("#myForm").validate({
onfocusout: false,
onkeyup: false,
rules: {
company1:{required:false},
company2: { 
          required: function(element) {
            return $("#company1").val() < 13;
  }
  }
}, 
messages: {
company2: {
    required: "Enter company 1"
}
}
```

Comment: Does your code really look like that under an editor? Perhaps you should take some time to format it so others can read it without much effort.

Answer (score 0):

```
rules: {
            company1: {
                required: false
            },
            company2: {
                required: function (element) {
                    var cmp1 = $("#company1").val();//cmpny 1 could be empty
                    if (cmp1.length > 0) {//if not empty
                        return cmp1 * 1 < 13;
                    } else {
                        return true;//if empty
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Here's the working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/KE9G4/3/)